# how to implement multiple countdowns on the same DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown, countdowntimer

I have a DOM element, that contains values (milliseconds) from my database, and I want to implement a countdown for the values. For example, I can have 4 product deals in a section, with different duration in milliseconds, and i want to dynamically create different countdowns(HH:mm:ss) for each deal according to its duration.
Currently, the duration values (milliseconds) are stored in a hidden input field for each deal in the section.

```
<input type="hidden" name="" id='duration' value="{{this.deals.duration}}">
```

What i tried (it works fine for only one product deal). I used `moment.js` for the duration. and also for the countdown here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('#duration').val());
    var interval = 1000;
    var durations = $('#duration').val();
    setInterval(function(){
      durations = moment.duration(durations - interval, 'milliseconds');
       // console.log(durations);
      $('#countdown').text(durations.hours() + ":" + durations.minutes() + ":" + durations.seconds())
    }, interval);
  })


</script>
```

Thanks very much :)

Comment: You would need to loop over it. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yh, Ikr, just cant seem to really get my head around it

Comment: the id attribute of elements is supposed to be unique. `$('#duration')` just select one.  if you have many `duration` and `countdown`, use a class is more proper. Could you paste your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var interval = 1000;
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.duration').each(function () {
      var t = Number($(this).val()) - interval;
      if (t>=0) {
        var d = moment.duration(t, 'milliseconds');
        $(this).next('.countdown').text([
          String(d.hours()).padStart(2,'0'),
          String(d.minutes()).padStart(2,'0'),
          String(d.seconds()).padStart(2,'0')
        ].join(':'));
        $(this).val(t);
      }
    });
  }, interval);
})
```

```css
input + span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="a" class='duration' value="5000"><span class="countdown"></span>

<input type="hidden" name="b" class='duration' value="15000"><span class="countdown"></span>

<input type="hidden" name="c" class='duration' value="20000"><span class="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution. it works, but you have to refresh the page 4-6 times before it starts displaying the correct allocated time.

Comment: I also noticed that after 3 product deals, it stop working

Comment: I believe that is a problem from my end, because I am sending a query lto the database to update the duration of milliseconds every milliseconds

Comment: About the starting problem, maybe you should wait for some ajax response instead of listening to the document 'ready event.
About the update problem, if you need such a high latency you should uses websockets.

Answer (score 1):

To add another answer to this question...

No dependencies (jQuery,Moment.js) and only for 24 hour duration (days,months,years are not calculated).

```js
function countDown(elClass) {
  let labels = document.querySelectorAll(elClass);
  let now = Date.now();
  labels.forEach((label,key) => {
  let duration = document.getElementById(label.getAttribute('for')).value;
  if(duration <= 86400000) {
    let futureDate = now + parseInt(duration);
    let counterInterval = setInterval(() => { 
      let diff = futureDate - Date.now();
      if(diff <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counterInterval);
        return;
      }
      if(diff > 0) { 
        let milliseconds = diff%1000;
        let seconds = parseInt(diff/1000)%60;
        let minutes = parseInt(diff/(60*1000))%60;
        let hours = parseInt(diff/(60*60*1000))%24;
        label.innerHTML = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')+':'+minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')+':'+seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')+'<br>';
      }
    },1000);
  }
  });
}
countDown('.countdown');
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="a" id="a" class='duration' value="5000"><label for="a" class="countdown"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="b" id="b" class='duration' value="15000"><label for="b" class="countdown"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="c" id="c" class='duration' value="190000"><label for="c" class="countdown"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="d" id="d" class='duration' value="2003200"><label for="d" class="countdown"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="e" id="e" class='duration' value="20067100"><label for="e" class="countdown"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="f" id="f" class='duration' value="86023104"><label for="f" class="countdown"></label>
```